# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key (only happens on XAML Designer's design view)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, designer

**XAML Designer** design view shows

**An Exception was thrown**

**ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.**

**Parameter name: key**

StackTrace (see after photo)

**InnerException: None**

I have been struggling for few days on the following issue, which prevents me from using **XAML Designe**r's design view on every affected view.

Yesterday, I eventually managed to isolate this odd behaviour which it particulary hard to trace, since it happens only at design-time, and that seems a conflit between generic type and **DataGrid**'s ItemsSource property (System.Windows.Controls).

So, this is what is shown on the **design view**

[image]

> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue&
>   value)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridItemAttachedStorage.TryGetValue(Object
>   item, DependencyProperty property, Object& value)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.RestoreAttachedItemValue(DependencyObject
>   objectWithProperty, DependencyProperty property)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.SyncProperties(Boolean
>   forcePrepareCells)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.PrepareRow(Object item, DataGrid
>   owningDataGrid)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject
>   element, Object item)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.MS.Internal.Controls.IGeneratorHost.PrepareItemContainer(DependencyObject
>   container, Object item)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IItemContainerGenerator.PrepareItemContainer(DependencyObject
>   container)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.InsertContainer(Int32
>   childIndex, UIElement container, Boolean isRecycled)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.AddContainerFromGenerator(Int32
>   childIndex, UIElement child, Boolean newlyRealized, Boolean
>   isBeforeViewport)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(IItemContainerGenerator&
>   generator, IContainItemStorage& itemStorageProvider,
>   IContainItemStorage& parentItemStorageProvider, Object& parentItem,
>   Boolean& hasUniformOrAverageContainerSizeBeenSet, Double&
>   computedUniformOrAverageContainerSize, Double&
>   computedUniformOrAverageContainerPixelSize, Boolean&
>   computedAreContainersUniformlySized, IList& items, Object& item,
>   IList& children, Int32& childIndex, Boolean& visualOrderChanged,
>   Boolean& isHorizontal, Size& childConstraint, Rect& viewport,
>   VirtualizationCacheLength& cacheSize, VirtualizationCacheLengthUnit&
>   cacheUnit, Boolean& foundFirstItemInViewport, Double&
>   firstItemInViewportOffset, Size& stackPixelSize, Size&
>   stackPixelSizeInViewport, Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheBeforeViewport,
>   Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Size& stackLogicalSize,
>   Size& stackLogicalSizeInViewport, Size&
>   stackLogicalSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size&
>   stackLogicalSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Boolean&
>   mustDisableVirtualization, Boolean isBeforeFirstItem, Boolean
>   isAfterFirstItem, Boolean isAfterLastItem, Boolean skipActualMeasure,
>   Boolean skipGeneration, Boolean&
>   hasBringIntoViewContainerBeenMeasured, Boolean&
>   hasVirtualizingChildren)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl(Size
>   constraint, Nullable`1& lastPageSafeOffset, List`1&
>   previouslyMeasuredOffsets, Nullable`1& lastPagePixelSize, Boolean
>   remeasure)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridRowsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size
>   constraint)    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size
>   availableSize)    at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size
>   availableSize)    at
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()

[Sample project source code](http://web.sisgarbe.pt/sispub/WebShared/CodeSamples/DataGridBugProof.zip)

**MyViewModelbase.cs** (this is my generic view model base)

```
namespace BugProof.ViewModels
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class MyViewModelBase<TItem> where TItem : class
    {
        public List<TItem> Items { get; set; }
        public MyViewModelBase() { }
    }
}
```

**MyExtendedViewModel.cs** (this my extended view model, which will be based upon a **string** type)

```
namespace BugProof.ViewModels
{
    public class MyExtendedViewModel : MyViewModelBase<string>
    {
        public MyExtendedViewModel()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="BugProof.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:BugProof.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BugProof"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type vm:MyExtendedViewModel}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"                  
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>This is what you should se in the designer</TextBlock>
        <!--Try replacing following DataGrid by a ListBox or ListView-->
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs** (MainWindow's code behind)

```
using System.Windows;

namespace BugProof
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Complementary details:

- The behaviour does not occur if one replaces **DataGrid** control by a **Listbox**, **ListView** or **ItemsControl**
- I am using **Visual Studio 2015, Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3**
- Project is targeted to **.Net Framework 4.5**

Comment: Did you try to use a non-static default value for the collection, e.g. () => new List<TItem>()) ?

Comment: I think you should test when you do the get on Items if the returning value is null or not

Comment: Hi @Geert van Horrik. When I try with non-static default value, I get the same result. However, if replace List<TItem> by List<string> on my MyViewModelBase class, everything works. It seems a conflit with generic type.

Comment: I now had managed to reproduce the same behaviour without Catel, so this is not Catel-related issue. I will updated my question to reflect this finding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting **IsDesignTimeCreatable=True** on **MainWindows.xaml** did the trick, although it requires special care implementing view model's parameters-less constructor, checking whether code is running in design-time or not.

[According to Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602277%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), setting **IsDesignTimeCreatable=True**, "specifies that the design instance is created from your type, instead of a designer-generated substitute type".

Surprisingly, also [according to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/windows/uwp/data-binding/displaying-data-in-the-designer#sample-data-from-class-and-design-time-attributes), if **IsDesignTimeCreatable** is not set or set to **False**, "all the design tool does is parse the class for its bindable properties".

I guess we have got two opposite truths. This may even be the case that both are really true, depending upon context. May be, the second source was not aware, at documentation writing time, the 3 samples that XAML Designer automatically generates once **IsDesignTimeCreatable** is set to default **False** value, whenever it finds a collection (IEnumerable) property

Until proof otherwise, this is a **WPF DataGrid** control bug when **ItemsSource** is binded to a generic collection source and **IsDesignTimeCreatable=False**, since this issue does not arise if we replace DataGrid control by **ListBox**, **ListView** or **ItemsControls**.

Comment: Mark this as the answer.

Comment: I have the same error occurring in a different context, when loading a (somewhat complicated) user control within a DataTemplate.

Comment: Normally I would be the last person to defend Microsoft, but truth be told, there are no opposite truths in the two "according to Microsoft" statements. `IsDesignTimeCreatable=True` will create an instance of your type.  `IsDesignTimeCreatable=False` (or missing) will not create an instance of your type; the designer will create a substitute instance by parsing your class for bindable properties.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this issue with the following:

1. increased the Designwidth
2. Revert Designwidth back to original.

FYI I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following line in XAML code

```
d:DataContext=""
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is simply to remove the "d:DataContext" attribute which will disable Datacontext related autocomplete.

I had to use this solution since the "IsDesignTimeCreatable" attribute, suggested by Julio, did not worked for me :/